# Magento logging with AWS Cloudwatch - UTC Offset format

Tags: magento-1.9, aws, logging

I'm trying to integrate Magento logs with AWS Cloudwatch.

My datetime_format configuration in the awslog.conf file:

```
datetime_format = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
```

Unfortunately, error messages occur:

```
Fall back to current time: {'timestamp': 1506379619020, 'start_position': 1645634L, 'end_position': 1645928L}, reason: timestamp could not be parsed from message.
```

Assuming that these result from the timestamp formatting, I have checked the AWS cloudwatch log documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html. It is written a bit ambiguously:

> The timezone offset (%z) is also supported even though it's not
>   supported until python 3.2, [+-]HHMM without colon(:).

While the written text could mean both (with or without colon is correct), it seems to me as if the correct format is *without* colon. Is there a way to take over the timestamps properly, or could they be modified in Magento beforehand?